# React triggering navigation from nested components

Tags: reactjs

I am new to React/RN and understand how navigation works, but don't really see a best practices for how to trigger navigation from a trivial component, like a random button somewhere, that should trigger a route change.

Let's say this button is nested under a set of elements who are under a `<Tab.Navigator>` who are under a set of `<Stack.Navigator>`, etc. A couple screen layouts deep. This element cannot access `this.props.navigation`. So my idea is to send upwards. But this could mean passing an `onPress` handler like, 5 or 6 layers down. Is this the correct way? Should I only pass it from the parent closest to a navigator, or all the way to `App.tsx`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can not use the `<Link>` component, then you should use the history object. 
For example, the `useHistory` hook will return it ( whenever you will import ), 
so your component can be nested as hell.

```
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom'

function HomeButton() {
  const history = useHistory()

  function handleClick() {
    history.push('/home')
  }

  return (
    <button type="button" onClick={handleClick}>
      Go home
    </button>
  )
}
```